# Select document by _id accessing database from MongoDB MLAB in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to access the document from MongoDB which was hosted on MLab but getting following error while access document with _id. Following is code for your reference

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('mongodb://<<UserName>>:<<Password>>@aadds157248.mlab.com:57248/<<DatabaseName>>',['temp1']);
router.get('/todo/:id',function(req,res,next){
var ObjectID = mongojs.ObjectID;
var o_id = new ObjectID (req.params.id);
db.temp1.findOne({
   '_id': o_id
},
function(err,temp1){
    if (err){
        res.send(err);
    }
    else {
        res.json(temp1);
    }
})
});
```

But getting below error when try to access the URL : http://localhost:3000/api/v1/todo/5870f7f1f36d2872530d26f1

TypeError: hex is not a function
   at Function.from (native)
   at Function.from (native)
   at new ObjectID (C:\Kamlesh\Angular2\meantodos\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\objectid.js:52:32)
   at C:\Kamlesh\Angular2\meantodos\routes\todos.js:23:14
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Kamlesh\Angular2\meantodos\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
   at next (C:\Kamlesh\Angular2\meantodos\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
   at Route.dispatch (C:\Kamlesh\Angular2\meantodos\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Kamlesh\Angular2\meantodos\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
   at C:\Kamlesh\Angular2\meantodos\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
   at param (C:\Kamlesh\Angular2\meantodos\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:349:14)

Comment: Can you print req.params.id and see what value you are getting on server side ? do console.log(req.params.id);

Comment: @Sumeet Yes, I tried get the value which I am sending from URL as mentioned in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting today a similar error related with some **mongodb-core** update.

I fixed it by forcing mongodb-core to the previous version i had:

```
npm install --save mongodb-core@1.3.18
```

Anyway, the first thing you have to check is that **req.params.id** has a valid hexadecimal 25 char string.